# How to reserve tcp source port on linux?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp, nat

I'm working on simple traffic tunneling solution (Linux).

1. Client side creates `tun` interface, routes all traffic on it, packages all arrived packets and sends to the server side via `udp` or `tcp` connection.
2. Server side expected to work like `NAT`. Change source ip address, source port (for tcp/udp) put packet on external network interface via `sock_raw`, listen for response via `sock_raw`, keep map of original-source-port <-> replaced-source-port and send responses back to the client.

**The question is**: how should I choose `replaced-source-port` ? OS chooses them from [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). I can't choose it by myself, it would cause conflicts. OS kernel chooses port after I send packet via `sock_raw` and I have no chance to build original-source-port <-> replaced-source-port map. Even if I choose port by myself – OS kernel will reply with `tcp` `rst` to all incoming tcp packets with `dst port` not associated with particular app.

P.S. I'm not sure on the overall solution for tunneling too. Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Should I just create a `socket` for each new connection and use `bind` to ask kernel to associate port with it ? Is it correct way and will tell kernel not to reply with `rst` ?

Comment: `bind` approach doesn't seems to be working. It does acquires `src port` but kernel still answers with `rst` to incoming `tcp` packets. I don't want to disable `rst` globally, it looks hacky.